# Reading macro value from generated/compile.h

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, procfs

I am trying to create a `procfs` entry. In linux kernel, I modify the `scripts/mkcompile_h` file to get timestamp value which is written to temperory generated file `include/generated/compile.h`. When I try to read that value (Eg: UTS_VERSION) from include/generated/compile.h (even `/proc/version` uses same logic to get details), I get some different value for time (some lesser seconds).

For printing macro value as proc entry, I just use `seq_printf(m, MACRO_VALUE);`. I dont understand the reason for not getting exact MACRO value as in `proc/version`. Even the `KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION` is wrong, it gives one less value than the macro value specified in `include/generated/compile.h` when I do `seq_printf(m, UTS_VERSION);`.

Sample `generated/compile.h` file:

`#define UTS_MACHINE "arm"`

`#define UTS_VERSION "#2 SMP PREEMPT Day Month Date hh:mm:ss IST year"`

Expected output:
`#2 SMP PREEMPT Day Month Date hh:mm:ss IST year`

But I get following output:
`#1 SMP PREEMPT Day Month Date hh:mm:ss-somevalue IST year`

Comment: I'm totally lost. Care to rethink your question and put it clearly?

Comment: @0andriy I have updated the question. Could you please check?

Comment: Elaborate how is defined `MACRO_VALUE` and `UTS_VERSION` in your case? Better to provide a code snippet.

Comment: @0andriy Updated.

Comment: And if you use *seq_printf(m, "%s", UTS_VERSION)* instead does it work?

Comment: @0andriy No the value differs.

Comment: You need to amend your question. Perhaps you need to add what is result, what is expected result with **real code snippets and examples**.